# Does this equality hold for all lattices with a top?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $(L,\land,\lor)$ be a lattice with maximal element $1$.

Let $p_1,...,p_n,q_1,...,q_m \in L: \lor_{i=1}^n p_i=\lor_{j=1}^m q_i =1$.

Is it guaranteed that  $\lor_{i=1}^n \lor_{j=1}^m (p_i \land q_j)=1$, or is distributivity required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hold for all lattices.

For example, consider the [diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties), $\mathbf M_3$, with middle elements $p_1, q_1$ and $p_2=q_2$.
It follows that $p_1 \vee p_2 = q_1 \vee q_2 = 1$, but
$$(p_1\wedge q_1) \vee (p_1 \wedge q_2) \vee (p_2 \wedge q_1) \vee (p_2 \wedge q_2) = 0 \vee 0 \vee 0 \vee p_2 \neq 1.$$

Distributivity is also not strictly necessary, for consider the [pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties), $\mathbf N_5$, with middle elements $p_1 < q_1 || p_2=q_2$ (here, $x || y$ means that $x\nleq y$ and $y \nleq x$).
It follows that $p_1 \vee p_2 = q_1 \vee q_2 = 1$ and
$$(p_1\wedge q_1) \vee (p_1 \wedge q_2) \vee (p_2 \wedge q_1) \vee (p_2 \wedge q_2) = p_1 \vee 0 \vee 0 \vee p_2 = 1.$$

Of course the implication holds if the lattice is distributive, but I suppose that is clear to you.

Comment: Thank you!

Do you have any idea whether there is some natural property equivalent with this condition?

Comment: @MichałZapała Notice that the condition is already a very natural one. It is called a quasi-equation, or [quasi-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiidentity), which is an important concept in Universal Algebra. You might be thinking if this class of lattices may, in alternative, be defined by a set of equations, thus making it a variety. I don't know if that is the case, but I think that could be a interesting question. Notice that's what happens with modular lattices, which are usually defined using a quasi-equation, but can also be defined by an equation.

Comment: I suppose you are right. It's just that this condition is very similar to what I'm trying to guarantee by that - rephrasing it, for instance, with equations or by forbidding certain sublattices, as it's the case with distributivity, would make my reasoning look, well, slightly cooler :p I haven't seen it anywhere, guess I'll just have to search on my own

Comment: You can't replace it by equations. I didn't remember in the last comment, but it's easy to come up with an example of lattice satisfying that property having a homomorphic image that doesn't. If you know about HSP theorem from Universal Algebra, that implies that the class of lattices satisfying that condition is not equational.